# Python - Giving Commands as argument

Tags: python

Is it possible to give the command to Python as argument instead of writing it in a file?

For example contents of file `Hello.py` are :

```
=========================
print"Hello World!"
=========================
```

When we do :

```
$ Python Hello.py
```

Its says :

```
Hello World!
```

But is it possible to give command diretly as Python argument :
Like :

```
$python <Some Option> "print 'hello World!'"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`-c` option](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c):

> Execute the Python code in command. command can be one or more statements separated by newlines, with significant leading whitespace as in normal module code.

**Example:**

```
python -c "print 'Hello World!'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
cmdargs = sys.argv
print cmdargs[1]
```

**$python file.py this_is_argument**

**this_is_argument**

It takes the input from command line and prints the same.